# Sorry-Cypress --> RequestError: Error: Invalid URI "/runs" when running the tests in parallel

Tags: cypress

I was trying to run the cypress tests in parallel using sorry-cypress. Getting below error when i  run the scripts in parellel. Can someone help on how can i resolve this issue?

npx cy2 run  --record --key XXX --parallel --ci-build-id 'build01'

C:\sorry-cypress-demo>npx cy2 run  --record --key XXX --parallel --ci-build-id 'build01'
npm does not support Node.js v15.3.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
[cy2] Running cypress with API URL: "http://localhost:1234/"

We encountered an unexpected error talking to our servers.

We will retry 3 more times in 30 seconds...

The server's response was:

RequestError: Error: Invalid URI "/runs"
We encountered an unexpected error talking to our servers.

We will retry 2 more times in 1 minute...

The server's response was:

RequestError: Error: Invalid URI "/runs"
We encountered an unexpected error talking to our servers.

We will retry 1 more time in 2 minutes...

The server's response was:

RequestError: Error: Invalid URI "/runs"
We encountered an unexpected error talking to our servers.

We will retry 0 more times in ...

The server's response was:

RequestError: Error: Invalid URI "/runs"
We encountered an unexpected error talking to our servers.

Because you passed the --parallel flag, this run cannot proceed because it requires a valid response from our servers.

The --ciBuildId flag you passed was: 'build01'

The server's response was:

RequestError: Error: Invalid URI "/runs"

Comment: Did you see the message says Node v15.3.0 is not supported? Did you attempt to fix that problem?

Comment: Yes - I have updated it to latest node version v16.16.0. Still same problem..

Comment: Are you saying you updated to `v16.16.0` but the error still says `v15.3.0`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if helps you too but for me works, when I correctly set up CYPRESS_API_URL. Something like this:

> cross-env CYPRESS_API_URL=http://localhost:1234/ cy2 run --parallel --record --key XXX --config-file cypress.config.ts --ci-build-id 'build01'